# Make switch look similar in both on/off condition

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make my switch look similar in both on/off condition. Same color of round thumb and same background color. Does anyone know how to do?

EDIT:

```
Switch chooser = (Switch) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dswitch);

    ColorStateList buttonStates = new ColorStateList(
            new int[][]{
                    new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked},
                    new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_enabled},
                    new int[]{}
            },
            new int[]{
                    Color.RED,
                    Color.RED,
                    Color.GREEN
            }
    );
    chooser.setButtonTintList(buttonStates);
```

Btw my Switch is in an custom alert dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method:

First use SwitchCompat in place of a Switch

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/switchInput"
        android:theme="@style/ColorSwitchStyle"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And have a style for this particular Switch in your styles.xml file:

```
<style name="Color1SwitchStyle">
        <item name="colorControlActivated">#491010</item>
        <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">#491010</item>
    </style>
```

Change color values as per your requirement and you are good to go.

-----------------------******---------------------------------------

You can try this for your Switch:

```
ColorStateList buttonStates = new ColorStateList(
        new int[][]{
                new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked},
                new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_enabled},
                new int[]{}
        },
        new int[]{
                Color.RED,
                Color.BLUE,
                Color.GREEN
        }
);
switchInput.setButtonTintList(buttonStates);
```

You can change the color for state_checked and state_enabled for a same color.

Comment: Thanks it worked. Can to tell me where you get all those tag for use in styles.xml?